# I'm using Xamarin Studio and the application output won't take in any user input

Tags: c#, xamarin

Forgive me if I use any wrong or confusing terms. I've been using Xamarin Studio and coding with C# for about a year now. Today I updated Xamarin Studio on my Mac, and found that my program was running in the application output instead of the terminal. Unlike the terminal, the application output doesn't seem to do anything when it gets to a point in the code that requires a user to add input. It's as if it's not reading Console.ReadLine(). 
Here's a simple example:

```
int num;
Console.Write("Type in an integer ");
num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine(num);
```

Normally, when using the terminal, this simple piece of code works just fine. I type an integer in the console, and then the program can display it. But the application output stops at

```
num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())
```

and doesn't let me type in an integer, and then just returns 0, since I never really defined it. How do fix this problem? Sorry if I don't describe this properly, I'm an amateur at this. Thank you.

Comment: That code works on my Mac with Mono 4.6.0/XS6.1....

Comment: Try System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine